# Using RQ with a Docker container hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, docker, heroku

A client has a goal to use Heroku for a project, but I'm stuck on how to make it work.

Basically, I need to run a function that takes around 15 seconds and depends on a custom repo, scipy, and some other dependencies that are typically NOT hosted on Heroku. So I turned the app into a docker container and pushed it to Heroku. So far so good.

The results of that function need to be returned via an API response. So I planned to use RQ for a task queue, and set up a worker process. Since my app is already using Docker, I had to stick with another docker container for the worker.

I can submit the task via the main app, and the worker takes over. However, the worker is in a separate docker container and cannot import the function. If I move the function completely to the worker, then I have the same problem in that I am unable to import the function into the main app when I call enqueue.

Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this? I feel like it is a complete mess right now.

Comment: It shouldn't be an impediment to have the main app and worker in each container. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, I am getting an error when the worker tries to run the function app.get_position. The error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'.

Comment: Can you please post your complete logs and piece of your code?

Comment: Of particular interest would be the Dockerfile or compose file; the two containers should be built with the same, complete codebase.